# Effect of virtual environment on program execution in pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, python-venv

In an attempt to generate an executable file for a tkinter application
using pyinstaller...

I installed pyinstaller globally while my tkinter application was in
a virtual environment. Whenever I ran the generated executable file, it would
throw a `ModuleNotFoundError` for one of the external packages I used (PIL)
even if the virtual environment was activated or not.

One of the solutions I came across was to pass command-line arguments like
`--add-data=<location of PIL package in the venv folder>`.

The confusion now is that I thought that if the virtual environment
was activated, the path to the PIL package inside the virtual env
is already exposed to the Python path,
so pyinstaller should "pick it up"?

The second scenario: I installed pyinstaller in the same virtual environment
that runs my tkinter application, the generated executable runs without any error (
no ModuleNotFoundError).

I would like to understand the technical nit-bit of why the first scenario
required extra maneuvering to work while the second scenario works without
any tweaking?

Answer (score 0):

**Description:**

Thats because in the first scenario PyInstaller was installed globally and tried to find the installed packages inside the Global directory of Python packages and not inside of a virtual environment as that is a separate working space.

Now, the question is why is it only showing `ModuleNotFoundError` for PIL only?

Well that's because every other package may have been found by the PyInstaller inside of the Global Package directory except PIL.

Now, for the second scenario where PyInstaller was installed inside of the virtual environment, PyInstaller is programmed to detect the origin working directory and if it finds the current directory to be a `venv` it automatically adds all the packages within the `Lib` packages folder. Hence the reason why you didn't have to add the PIL package manually.